# How to select a specific result if multiple results are returned from Google's geocoder.geocode service

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've created this dropPin function to get geo-coordinates from Google's geocoder.geocode service to set a marker and populate a couple hidden form fields.  However, `results` can contain more than one `GeocoderResults` object literal arrays as per [their docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResponses).  I can't figure out how I reference one particular result object over another.

```
function dropPin() {

     var address = document.getElementById("map-search-input").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {   

          latLng = results[0].geometry.location;

          marker.setPosition(latLng);

          document.getElementById("lat").value=latLng.lat();
          document.getElementById("lng").value=latLng.lng();

       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
```

Comment: What are you using the results for? You need to process through the types and/or the formatted address for the one that best meets your needs (which you haven't specified).  Or you could present them all to your user and let them choose.

Comment: Mike Williams describes the process on [this page](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/didyoumean.htm) of his Google Maps API v2 tutorial.  The details will be different for v3 but the principle is the same.

Comment: @geocodezip I want to have a look at the address data provided and choose the most appropriate one.  If none are appropriate (such as only approximate location), I want to prompt the user to change their input.  I'll play around with some of the ideas in the article you linked to.  Thanks